# Ruby and rails with Omniauth - google and openid error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openid, omniauth

I'm using omniauth 0.1.5 with rails 2.3.8 and have managed to implement both Twitter and Facebook authentication.  Openid, however, is giving me some issues, namely the following:

WARNING: making https request to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/.well-known/host-meta?hd=www.google.com without verifying server certificate; no CA path was specified.
  SQL (0.1ms)   SET NAMES 'utf8'
  SQL (0.1ms)   SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0
Performing discovery for https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
Discovering user identity https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id for domain www.google.com
Cache read: __GAPPS_OPENID__www.google.com
Unexpected exception performing discovery for id https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id: Error fetching https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/.well-known/host-meta?hd=www.google.com: Connection refused - connect(2)

This is the call in the environment.rb : use OmniAuth::Strategies::OpenID, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'

I am behind a proxy, so I think that may have a part to play but the error message is a little vague.  Also, I have set the proxy elsewhere.

Any ideas?

As always, cheers.

Slothistype

Comment: Using curl, I have noticed that I cannot connect to  https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id so I think this is a SSL issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was a proxy issue and was solved with setting the http  proxy env correctly.